# Code signing an ionic based android APK

Tags: android, ionic-framework, code-signing

I'm new to Ionic and mobile so my knowledge of code signing is limited. I started at a new company and I've been put in control of a ionic mobile application. I successfully signed and deployed to the ios store but am struggling with Android.

I can see the app signing certificate and the upload certificate in the google play store but I'm not sure what to do next. I keep reading that I need the same key that the app was initially submitted to the playstore with but is that the upload certificate or is that something specific to the developer that originally uploaded it with. I guess my question is, is this even possible given the certificates I have access to without the original key the developer may have used?

Any help and advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Is it an application that is already present in play store? or is a new application that is being submitted to play store for the first time.

1. If that is a new application then you need to create a new jks file which should be kept safe as you will be using it every time to generate a signed apk file when ever you push the application to play store.
2. If that is an existing application in playstore there should be an existing .jks file which was used to generate a signed apk file. And now while pushing the application you need to generate signed apk using the same jks.

Let me know if you want to know how to generate a signed apk or create a .jks file.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. This is an app that is already in the playstore. The only key I have access to right now is the upload.der file that is hosted in the playstore. I don't have the original jks file that was used to sign the apk. I read that I could create a new jks file and export the upload.der file into it and then submit this to google to change the key. I read that here: http://ghoulkeeper.com/lost-keystore-how-to-generate-and-register-a-new-upload-key-mac/

Comment: Follow the steps accordingly and let me know if you are able to generate .jks file successfully or not.

Comment: I can generate the jks file just fine. It’s signing the apk file and successfully uploading it to the play store that I’m having trouble with because they already have a key on file that I don’t have so I’m trying to get them to update it.

Comment: Good to hear you are able to generate the jks file. I didnt get you for the second line. I understood it something like this "you are not able to generate signed apk because you dont know the key for jks to genreate signed apk". Is this what you are trying to suggest.